# Port forwarding not working as expected

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

Im running a laptop connected to a router connected to the internet.
Public ip of the router is not one of the ip's used for private networks (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), and Im able to edit the virtual server/NAT forwarding settings of the router.

I have forwarded traffic received on the external port 1200 of the router to my laptop's private IP address, same port. I have a cheroot (cherrypy) server listening on port 1200.

An lsof command confirms cheroot is listening on 1200, initialized with the right python file.

When I scan my routers private IP address (192.168.0.1) for open ports, 1200 is not one of the open ports (which is to be expected, from Bodos comment, and which I now understand).

My router has an ipv4 and ipv6 SPI firewall enabled.

Ive added an A record to my domain name provider pointing to my router's public ip and an SRV record pointing to my routers external port (1200).

However the website Im trying to access isn't accessible (server took too long to respond, website cant be reached).
I tried using https://canyouseeme.org to see if port 1200 is open when I hit my router's public ip, I get a connection timed out response.

Additional deets, unsure if they're relevant or not:

1. I then used a python port scan script, connected my laptop to a hotspot, ran the script and checked for all open ports on my routers public ip. Zero ports open.
2. The cheroot server serves up my app nicely on the local, private network.
3. I just installed Nmap and I'm itching to use it. :-)
4. A trace route to the routers private ip while connected to the router works as expected. While using a 4g hotspot from my phone though, a trace route from my laptop to the routers public ip fails.
5. I tried accessing the site with both the firewalls switched off, didn't help.

Can anyone help me understand what Im missing here?

Is there a way to run a netstat on the router maybe? Have a hunch port forwarding has not been really taken effect, or incoming connections are blocked. How do I evaluate any of these possibilities?

Update: My router is behind another ISP router. Routers ip in its admin panel doesn't match my public ip.

Thats it then, I guess. ISP must be asked to enable port forwarding to my router now? Double NAT? No other solution except for something like ngrok, right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "Public ip of the router is a class A ip"?

Comment: Use tools like Wireshark to see if the router forwards packets when you try from the external network (internet). If the router is configured to forward from the external interface to the local network you won't see an open port when you scan from the local network.

Comment: What model is your router? Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1727942/edit) your post and add a screenshot of the port-forwarding page of the router.

Comment: @user1686, I wrote that incorrectly. Edited now

Comment: @Bodo, by any chance can Nmap do the same? I already have it. Lol. Just need to dive into that rabbit hole

Comment: Also, is there a way to run netstat on a router? Id like to see if its even receiving incoming new http / https connections, because I think that also may be disabled for my connection.

Comment: @Bodo that makes sense to me. But if I can from outside the network too, this port isn't open. Absolutely no ports open as per the scan, so it shouldn't be forwarding any packets at all

Comment: Please provide the first two octets of your public IP address as indicated in your router's web interface (for example *192.168.x.x*).

Comment: 103.219...... Im curious. What's your thinking here?

Answer (score -1):

> when I scan my routers private IP address (192.168.0.1) for open ports, 1200 is not one of the open ports.

That's entirely normal. The port forwarding aka destination NAT works *from the public WAN IP address*. You need to try on from outside your LAN, using the router's public IP address. Also make sure that you've configured the laptop's local firewall to permit that connection.

If everything fails either the router's port forwarding is broken, or there's a firewall feature on the router that you'd also need to configure, or your ISP is blocking incoming connections.

Comment: Yup. Realised this from @Bodo's comment, responded. Scans from outside the nw using my phone on a 4g connection with an ipv6 address also indicate the external port on the router I want to forward is still closed.

Comment: I have a hunch incoming connections are blocked and there's a firewall in place. How could I validate these two hunches?

Comment: IPv6 and IPv4 cannot talk to each other. Port forwarding is only used for IPv4, IPv6 doesn't need that but requires firewall rules to enable forwarding inside.